# How to get value from a table referenced from foreign key on Hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have two tables in my database, author and book. Here is the structure for both of them:

Book table:

```
@Entity
public class Book {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String title;

    @ManyToOne
    private Author author;

    ...getters and setters...
}
```

Author table:

```
@Entity
public class Author {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;

    ...getters and setters
}
```

I would like to get the Author of a specific Book, by the book's title. I've reached this with this sql command on terminal: `select author.name as author from author right join book on author.id = book.author_id where book.title='Some title';`. How should I structure the query in my code to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This would be the equivalent query

```
select a.name as author from author a right join book b where b.title = 'Some title'
```

in code

```
entityManager.createQuery("select a.name as author from author a right join book b where b.title = ? ").setParameter(1, "Some title");
```

Comment: It doesn't works. It's throwing an `SQLSintaxErrorException`

Comment: Still not working, same exception. I think maybe I should change the type of relationship

Answer (score 0):

Guess it was much easier than I thought. Instead of using a complex query, I just fetched the book by its title and then fetched the author by its id, just like this, and it worked just fine:

```
Query query = manager.createQuery("select b from book b where b.title = :myTitle")
            .setParameter("myTitle", "Some title");

Book book = (Book) query.getSingleResult();
Author author = manager.find(Author.class, book.getAuthor().getId());

System.out.println(author.getName());
```